# Making One Column of DataGridView AutoComplete for String Data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, autocomplete

I am trying to set up a DataGridView in VB.Net where a single column, called "Supplier" acts as a TextBox with an AutoCompleteSource to help users with entering data.  This is the code I put together to attempt to accomplish this:

```
Private Sub OrderData_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles orderData.EditingControlShowing
    Dim colIndex = orderData.SelectedCells.Item(0).ColumnIndex
    Dim headerText As String = orderData.Columns(colIndex).HeaderText
    If headerText.Equals("Supplier") Then
        Dim autoText As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
        If autoText IsNot Nothing Then
            autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = FillTextBoxData("supplier_name", "suppliers")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I kind of works.  Unfortunately it adds AutoCompletes to every single editable column in the table, instead of just the "Supplier" column (column index 2).

What do I need to do to fix this?

EDIT: I modified the code a bit to try and fix the issue, and it kind of worked.  If I don't selected the "Supplier" column first, then the other columns to not contain an AutoComplete.  However if I go from the "Supplier" column to another column, then it contains an AutoComplete.  How do I fix this?

Comment: After you select supplier, you say the autocomplete goes active on all, it stays active after you have selected other cells? or jsut the first one after supplier?

Comment: Once I have tried typing into the Supplier Column, if I move to another column on that row it will have the AutoComplete attached to it.  However if I go to a column that isn't Supplier first, then there is no AutoComplete on it, until after I've tried editing the Supplier column.

Comment: while i doubt this works, can you add an else to the outter if that sets e.Control =nothing

Comment: I can't set e.Control = Nothing because e.Control is ReadOnly

Comment: mmm how about in an outter else add Dim autoText As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox) And then  autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.none

Comment: I agree with @cg7 … add an `Else` clause to the `If headerText.Equals("Supplier") Then` statement. In the `Else` portion add the line `autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None`.

Comment: @cg7 Sorry for the late reply, but that actually worked to fix my issue.  Thank you very much :)

Comment: i will add it to my answer then so ppl with the same problem can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
Dim headerText As String = orderData.Columns(2).HeaderText
If headerText.Equals("Supplier") Then
```

That will be always true, since you are always getting the col 2 header no matter what cell is selected, you need to add that, something like

```
Dim colIndex = orderData.SelectedCells.Item(0).ColumnIndex
```

then you can use your code

```
Dim headerText As String = orderData.Columns(colIndex).HeaderText
```

Also add an `Else` clause to the `If headerText.Equals("Supplier") Then` statement. In the `Else` portion add the line `autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None`

Comment: I made your suggested change, but I am still getting other columns set up with AutoCompletes.  I even ran through the debugger and the AutoComplete is still getting added to the other columns on the row even if the `headerText` if statement is false and it doesn't run over that section of code.

Comment: mmm weird, if you commend the entire function, it still happens? if so, you may be binding in another place in your code, try commenting this entire funcion and see if still autocompletes